# run UDFs in parallel in Spark DataFrame for a given row

Tags: apache-spark

Consider the following dataframe API code:

```
df
.withColumn("resultA",expensiveUDF($"inputA"))
.withColumn("resultB",expensiveUDF($"inputB"))
.show()
```

both UDF calls will run sequentially as they are in the same task. Is there a way to have those UDF-calls run at the same time? As they are independent from each otherm this should not be too difficukt.

I tried to increase `spark.task.cpus` but this did not solve the issue.

I know there is a way to use multi-threading in Spark within UDF code, but thats not what I want to do.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not up to you to multithread in Spark, you let Spark do it for you. What should happen is that the `df` dataframe is split into N parititons. Then "A" and "B" transformations are applied to each of the N partitions independently and at the same time (on as many partitions/processors you have available). If this does not happen, you need to investigate if / whay `df` has only one partition. It may be a single input file in a non splittable format (e.g. a single ZIP file), or it may have been repartitionned to size 1, which defeats multithreading by design.

Comment: @GPI I'm aware of that. My issue is that sometimes df has only 1 row, in this case I have no parallelism at all. But most of the time I have records which have a considerable skew, measing that the udf takes very long for certain rows. It would therefore help if I could distribute those long calls to different threads/tasks to reduce skew

Comment: Maybe a bit convoluted, but could you perhaps `explode(array('inputA, 'inputB))` and run the `expensiveUDF` on the exploded column (should be parallelised by Spark) and later on group the records back together?

Comment: Short answer is there is no such option. But reading between the lines it sounds like the XY-problem, likely related to usage of `collect_list` or other `groupByKey` equivalent, and if that's the case, this is the part that should be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the two withColumns in a single line

```py
df
.withColumn("resultA_and_resultB",expensiveUDF($"inputA", $"inputB"))
.show()
```

Modify the expensiveUDF to have many arguments. Finally the column can be split into two columns. This way you need not worry about running the two statements parallelly.